# AngularJS - updating page view on select dropdown change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created two dropdown lists using select tag, and i would like to make second dropdown option values to be updated based on first dropdown selection, and based on second dropdown selection, update values underneath.

I've heard that i can use $apply, but i don't have an idea where to put it and how to use it. I would apreciate any suggestio,n what should I change in order for this to work.

These are my files.

```css
angular.module('app', []).controller('contr', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
  {
      name: 'Ala',
      holiday: [
                { month: 'June', location: ['Rome', 'Wien'] },
                { month: 'July', location: ['Budapest', 'Bucharest'] },
                { month: 'August', location: ['Warsaw', 'Prague']}
      ]
  },
  {
      name: 'Bob',
      holiday: [
              { month: 'January', location: ['Paris', 'Madrid'] },
              { month: 'February', location: ['London', 'Dublin'] },
      ]
  }
    ];

    $scope.person = $scope.data[0];
    $scope.holidays = $scope.person.holiday;
    $scope.holiday = $scope.holidays[0];
    $scope.locations = $scope.holiday.location;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='app' ng-controller='contr'>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>

    Person:<select ng-model='person' ng-options='info as info.name for info in data'></select></br>
    Month:<select ng-model='holiday' ng-options='holiday as holiday.month for holiday in holidays'></select></br>
 </br>Places:</br>
    <div ng-repeat='location in locations'>Location: {{location}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of adding watch in your case. Try this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='app' ng-controller='contr'>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', []).controller('contr', function ($scope) {

            $scope.data = [
                    {
                        name: 'Ala',
                        holiday: [
                            {
                                month: 'June',
                                location: ['Rome', 'Wien']
                            },
                            {
                                month: 'July',
                                location: ['Budapest', 'Bucharest']
                            },
                            {
                                month: 'August',
                                location: ['Warsaw', 'Prague']
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Bob',
                        holiday: [
                            {
                                month: 'January',
                                location: ['Paris', 'Madrid']
                            },
                            {
                                month: 'February',
                                location: ['London', 'Dublin']
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ];

            $scope.SetMonthValue = function(){
                $scope.holiday = $scope.person.holiday[0];
            }
            
            $scope.person = $scope.data[0];
            $scope.holidays = $scope.person.holiday;
            $scope.holiday = $scope.holidays[0];
            $scope.locations = $scope.holiday.location;
        });
    </script>


    Person:
    <select ng-model='person' ng-change="SetMonthValue()" ng-options='info as info.name for info in data'></select>
    Month:
    <select ng-model='holiday' ng-options='holiday as holiday.month for holiday in person.holiday'></select>    
    Location
    <select ng-model='location' ng-options='location for location in holiday.location'></select>

    <div>Location: {{holiday.location}}</div>    
    
    <div>Third dropdown value: {{location}}</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Since you need the second select option depending on the value selected in the first, use the source as the first `ng-model` value of first select box,

I have extended that case to a third level in this example for further understanding i.e, added a third combo box for location based on value selected in second one.

Adding watch for these purposes is not a good solution. Try to avoid watch variables in maximum possible cases.

Comment: Working nicely, but if I want second dropdown default value to be set to first option, not empty value, then the watch is needed?

Comment: No. You can use ng-change event. Using watch is not a good method

Comment: @AdamKorzeniak I have included that too, updated the code

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.apply` is not needed here. You can use `apply` to make angular aware of scope changes outside of the angular's digest cycle.

`$watch` is what you want here

```
$scope.$watch('person', function(newPerson) {
    $scope.holidays = newPerson.holiday;
    $scope.holiday = $scope.holidays[0];
});
```

You could also change `ng-options` for holiday dropdown

```
<select ng-model='holiday' ng-options='holiday as holiday.month for holiday in person.holiday'></select>
```

From docs:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

`$apply` docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

`$watch` docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch